# XSLT won't render HTML tags

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm a beginner in XML. I use the book "XML: Visual Quickstart Guide" by Kevin Howard Goldberg. I've just learned how to transform XML files with XSLT. Everything you will see in my code is what I've learned until now about XML and XSLT.

I wanted to make an HTML table with the XML data in it, like this:

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog

but it only shows me the data in a row without rendering the HTML tags:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLECw.jpg

So why is my code not working?

This is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet content-type="application/xml" href="page2_xslt.xsl"?>
<favNumbers>
    <song>
        <title>Song 1</title> 
        <artist>Artist 1</artist>
    </song> 
    <song>
        <title>Song 2</title> 
        <artist>Artist 2</artist> 
    </song> 
    <song>
        <title>Song 3</title> 
        <artist>Artist 3</artist> 
    </song> 
    <song>
        <title>Song 4</title> 
        <artist>Artist 4</artist> 
    </song> 
</favNumbers>
```

This is my XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" /> 
<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Favorite Songs</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <table> 
            <tr>
                <th>Favorite Songs</th> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th> 
                <th>Artist</th> 
            </tr> 
            <xsl:for-each select="favNumbers/song">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td> 
                <td><xsl:value-of select="artist" /></td> 
            </tr> 
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table> 
    </body> 
</html>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's becoming really frustrating now. Did I miss a quote, a comma or anything else? Or is it something much more complex. I've searched for an answer on many sites, but I couldn't find one, maybe because English is not my first language. So please help me out.

Thank you :)

Comment: Cut-and-paste of the source code from your question into the corresponding textareas in the w3school playground from your example worked for me. The proper result with the column headers is displayed. I'm using Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this part in your XML:

```
<?xml-stylesheet content-type="application/xml" href="page2_xslt.xsl"?>
```

to:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="page2_xslt.xsl"?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It solved my problems in IE and FireFox but not in Chrome, but I just discovered that it's some kind of security issue in Chrome. I understand that Chrome can't render HTML tags in client-sided XML+XSLT files. So I uploaded them onto my testing site and it worked :)